# Cant send data from activity to activity

Tags: android

1- is my first activity(main)
2- is my second activity
3 - is my third activity

I want to run 2 from 1 and then form 2 run 3 , and then from 3 i am taking data and returning it to 1. Hope guys you will understand.

Here is my code:

Runing 2 form 1 liek this :

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MessageBox.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,5);
```

And then running 3 from 2 like this:

```
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ImageReceiver.class);

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
                startActivity(intent);
```

And then in 3 i have something like this:

```
          setResult(5);
          finish();
```

And then in 1 i got:

```
     if(requestCode==5)
     {
         if(resultCode==5)
         {
             //here i am taking data from 3
        // i am making here Toast to now if my program is here
         }
     }
```

Problem is that my app is not crashing but i am stucking in 2 activity. Even if i go with finish(); when starting 3 activity i i am not getting Toast that a i am making in 1 when my program succesfully get data from 3.

And i dont really get what should i do. Please look at this code.

Comment: Start activity 3 also with startActivityForResult() and do not finish activity 2 at that moment. In activity 2 in onActivityResult grab the result and do a setResult(resultCode); finish(); Moreover you have to grab the data from the result and put it again.

Comment: I was doing that but always i get same result my app stops in second activity and that really weird coz that should work fine

Comment: Put a Toast right in the beginning of onActivityResult which shows resultCode and requestCode. They will not both be 5.